# apache-tomcat-7 is not starting on centos

Tags: tomcat, centos, vps

I have installed apache-tomcat-7 and also added a script at /etc/init.d/tomcat that can start/stop/restart Apache Tomcat 7.0. Now, when i start the tomcat service it is not giving any error but i am unable to see it running on `http://my-ip-address:8080/`

And also when i am stopping the tomcat service a message with an exception displayed :-

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Aug 09, 2013 7:03:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
Aug 09, 2013 7:03:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:500)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:458)
```

This error message containing a line that `SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.` which may be telling that the server was not started. But i am wondering because before that i have also ran the command `service tomcat start`.

Sorry guys, i forgot to mention that i am doing this on a `VPS`, which is running `CentOs 6`.

Comment: All i am trying to do is, deploying a java web application on tomcat-server on a VPS which is running CentOS 6.

Comment: Might be helpful to include the source for `/etc/init.d/tomcat`. Does Tomcat work when launching it using `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/startup.sh`?

Comment: @Christopher Schultz thankyou for your reply. Actually I am getting this on launching it using startup.sh 

`Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
`

Comment: Hi all, i got my VPS running with tomcat. I just reprovisioned my VPS and install the tomcat7 using EasyApache wizard and then i deployed my application using tomcat manager and my appilcation is running now. This is the link i got while googling [link](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/Tomcat/TomcatIntroduction). Hope anyone else finding the solution for the same problem would get his/her problem solved using this link.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my experience is useful for somebody.

I deployed a WAR file (the deployed web application was writing some file on hard). I forgot to undeploy WAR file from tomcat and before undeployment, I just delete my web application from my computer hard disk.

When I tried to start Tomcat (/Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh), there was no error, but I could not open http://:8080/ on any browsers, and when I tried to shutdown Tomcat (/Library/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh), I got the above mentioned error (SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running).

I use this command (/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run) and I understood the above problem. Then I created the missing file, and start the tomcat, then undeploy the previously-deleted WAR file from tomcat and then shutdown tomcat (/Library/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh).

NOTE: keep in mind that first undeploy WAR file on tomcat and then delete the related project from your hard disk!!!